# Fourier transform of $sin(\frac{1}{x})$ for $x > 0 (x > 1)$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Please, give me the cue: does exist analytical representation of Fourier Transform of $sin(\frac{1}{x})$ for$ x>0$ (or $x>1$). Maybe exist an approximation of $FT(sin(\frac{1}{x}))$ by Bessel functions? Thank you.

Comment: Is this function even in $L^1$ or $L^2$?

Comment: Why do you need $L^1$ or $L^2$? It is a tempered distribution. In fact it is in $L^2$, it is like $1/x$ at infinity.

Comment: What is an "analytical representation"? Is not Fourier integral itself an analytical representation?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko True that but based on the lack of detail I wasn't sure what the level of understanding OP has. I would approach this via distributions.

Comment: Since $\int_0^\infty \exp(-ax-b/x) \, dx$ is basically a Bessel function
I'd expect that there's a formula for $\int_0^\infty \sin(1/x) \, e^{ixy} \, dx$
in terms of Bessel functions too.  But it looks like this question
will be closed before I can find this formula...  Try Gradshteyn & Ryzhik.

Answer (score 2):

The explicit answer is the formula 2.5.24.1 on page 433 from Brychkov, Marichev, Prudnikov Integral and Series, vol. 1. Note that for the odd function the FT reduces to sinT, and take $\alpha=1, \delta=1$. And yes, the answer is via Bessel and Macdonald functions.